# Cannot initialize variables in constructor that's using dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, autofac

I have a constructor that's getting its dependencies from a Dependency Injection framework (Autofac). The problem is I can not do anything else in the constructor except getting those dependencies, if I write any statement inside the constructor other than those dependency assignments, I get the following error:-

`No parameter less constructor is defined for this object`

I have to comment the assignment of readonly string shown below for this to work:-

```
public RelationshipController(ICustomerService customerService,)
{
   this.customerService = customerService;
   //someReadonlyString = "abcd";
}
```

Can somebody tell me, What's happening?

Comment: Adding an assignment to a constructor cannot cause this error. Can you post some more context? How you dependency resolver is set up? How is your container registration looks like? What is the exact error message, what is in the inner exception? Maybe there is a problem with the `ICustomerService` implementation not with the controller....

Comment: ..also, what is that `,` doing in the constructor signature?

Comment: I see a `RelationshipController` which probably means that you are using ASP.NET MVC (but you have not tags on this). You probably didn't register Autofac correctly in MVC. In that case, MVC will not use Aufofac and can only work with default constructors. Please show your configuration, and the complete exception + message + stack trace.

Comment: @Steven, it looks like you have the right answer, or are on the way to it.  Please flesh out & post your comment as an answer and maybe we can get this thing moving.

Answer (score 1):

When the requested service (in this case, `ICustomerService`) cannot be found in the container, Autofac will move on to look for a default (a.ka. the parameterless) constructor. You obviously have no default constructor, thus Autofac bails out with an exception.

My guess is that the real error here is in the registration code for the `ICustomerService` interface.

Comment: This code is not the real one, it was just to show the situation whats happening.

Comment: I have 3-4 dependencies being passed into constructor and everything is registered correctly, because: If I remove only the readonly string variable assignment, everything works fine.

Comment: @puretechy - ok, but that is why we need to see more of the picture, because what you're saying just does not compute. Autofac cares (and sees not) what your constructor is *doing*, only what the public signature looks like. Trim down your code to a compiling version that still exhibit the same symptom, then update your question. Then maybe we're able to help you spot the problem. Please also include the container registration code.

Comment: Peter, I have never seen that behavior.  I usually get a helpful "could not resolve <dependency> for <class> constructor <constructor-signature>," (or words to that effect).  I have never seen it "bail" with a lame "parameterless constructor not found" error.  Is that the behavior in an older version?

Comment: @MarcL. - me neither come to think of it. I suspect more and more that  Steven has it right, the exception does not come from Autofac. Searching both Autofac 1.x and 2.x sources doesn't reveal any such message!

Answer (score 0):

I see a RelationshipController which probably means that you are using ASP.NET MVC. You probably didn't register Autofac correctly in MVC. In that case, MVC will not use Aufofac and can only work with default constructors.